# How to modify table headers in the gtsummary package?

Tags: r, gtsummary

Very simple question, but I can't find a straightforward way of doing it.  I want to change the default text of a `tbl_summary` object to say "Variable" instead of "Characteristic" in the first column.  Example:

```
library(gtsummary)
library(dplyr)
head(trial)
trial2 =
  trial %>%
  dplyr::select(trt, marker, stage)
tbl_summary(trial2)
```

Looking through the documentation, it looks like this information is stored in a `.$table_header object` and I could just modify it directly, but I was wondering if there is a simple way to change the header names.  The function `modify_header()` seemed promising, but it doesn't appear to be able to change the names of the columns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct!  The `modify_header()` function is the way to go to update the column headers.

```r
library(gtsummary)
library(dplyr)

trial %>%
  select(trt, marker, stage) %>%
  tbl_summary() %>%
  modify_header(label = "**Variable**")
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect!  Is this documented?  I couldn't find `label` in the `modify_header` documentation: http://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/modify_header.html.  Thanks for the incredible package!

Comment: In the `modify_header()` help file we say, "Argument is the column name, and the value is the new column header (e.g. `p.value = "Model P-values"`). Use `print(x$table_body)` to see columns available." 

BUT you're the not first to have this question, and I think we need to make the syntax more obvious somehow!

Comment: Ah gotcha!  Thanks so much.